# How can I use dollar signs ($) in a Markdown code block in a way that renders correctly when converted to HTML?

Tags: html, markdown

I'm trying to write a block of code containing part of a Makefile script in a Markdown document.

If I write

```
<pre><code>FOO = $(BAR)
</code></pre>
```

then in multiple different Markdown previewers I'll see

```
FOO = $(BAR)
```

but when converted to HTML with various tools and opened in a browser, I see

```
FOO =
```

How can I write this such that it renders correctly in both a Markdown preview and in HTML?

Is it at all possible to use the 3-backtick (```) notation for code blocks in a way that works with HTML? I've found that it just literally prints the backticks when converted to HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Dollar sign can be printed using $\$$
This will be converted into a single '$' sign

Answer (score 2):

Consider using `&#36;` for $ when you use it within HTML.

Comment: You can also use `&dollar;` which is more readable and a little easier to remember https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: If you have multiple $ symbols on the same line, these two `&#36;` and `&dollar;` will also sometimes do math, same as regular `$`